# Modeling a random-effects component using the lme4 package

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I would like to estimate a generalized linear mixed-effects model using the `glmer.nb` function in R's `lme4` package. I have panel data of various crime outcomes. My cross-sectional unit is the "precinct" (over 40 precincts) and I observe crime in those precincts over many months. I am evaluating an intervention that 'turns on/off' (dummy coded) over the month-years. I include "precinct" and "month" fixed effects (i.e., a full set of precinct and month dummies enter the model). I have only one independent variable I am assessing. The *second* model using `glmer.nb` is the function that returns an error.

```
# How the two-way fixed-effects model is specified (works well)

model_fe <- glm.nb(crime_counts ~ as.factor(precinct) + as.factor(month_year) + policy, data = df)

# Modeling "precincts" as the random-effect (fails)

model_re <- glmer.nb(crime_counts ~ (1 | precinct) + as.factor(month_year) + policy, data = df)
```

The error returned is shown below...

```
failure to converge in 10000 evaluationsModel failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00295777 (tol = 0.001, component 1)iteration limit reached
```

In sum, I would like to specify precincts as the random intercept component. I also tried to specify precinct as a factor variable but that did not help. Any ideas? I am new to this package.

Comment: Perhaps you don't have enough data for a model of that complexity?

Comment: Check out <https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/33653_57fc7b8e5d484c909b615d8633c01d51.html> about some convergence checks and tweaks